# Jquery: How to apply a function to many ids

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a page of divs that I want only to appear if the proper link is clicked. Each div has an id corresponding to tag id to be displayed. For example for my tag with id 1, the link to click has an id="tag1s" and the div with the object information has an id="tag1". Here is my javascript that I want to work in the html:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('tag'+id+'s').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#tag'+id).toggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Currently this works if I put in the specific ids. But I want this to work for every id in my @tags. Here is the html:

```
<h1>Tags</h1>
<div class="home unlimited">
  <div class="flex-container top-row">
    <div class="tag-buttons">
        <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
            <%= link_to "#", id:"tag#{tag.id}s", class:"tag-btn"  do%>
                <div class="tag-button">
                    <%= tag.name %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="tag-button">
          <%= render :partial => 'layouts/create_tags', :locals => { :tag => Tag.new} %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tag-display">
      <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
        <div id=<%="tag#{tag.id}"-%> class="individual-tags">
            <%= render :partial => "show_display", :locals => { :courses => @tag_relation_c[tag], :lessons => @tag_relation_l[tag], :tag => tag } %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can make it so I can have the function work for every tag_id?

Comment: Move away from using `id`s as they require brittle code that you are now dealing with. Instead, consider using classes on elements that need to be treated the same way.

Comment: @marcus I tried using classes and it wouldn't work even for specific cases. If I used classes, wouldn't I run into the same issue?

Comment: Based on your example it looks like you could target all elements with class `individual-tags`.

Comment: But I only want specific divs to be visible, How would I make it so only the specific div with the tag_id becomes visable, but not the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's close.  Just make the selector on a class for the button press and read the **id** off an attribute of the button, something like this...

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('tag-btn').click(function(event) {
      var id = $(this).data('tag-id');
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#tag'+id).toggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Then change your markup accordingly...

```
<h1>Tags</h1>
<div class="home unlimited">
  <div class="flex-container top-row">
    <div class="tag-buttons">
        <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
            # The line below is all that changes
            <%= link_to "#", class:"tag-btn", data: { tag_id: tag.id % } do%>
                <div class="tag-button">
                    <%= tag.name %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="tag-button">
          <%= render :partial => 'layouts/create_tags', :locals => { :tag => Tag.new} %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tag-display">
      <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
        <div id=<%="tag#{tag.id}"-%> class="individual-tags">
            <%= render :partial => "show_display", :locals => { :courses => @tag_relation_c[tag], :lessons => @tag_relation_l[tag], :tag => tag } %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and even add the "." to ".tag-btn", but the tag_id data is not passing through. When I do a console.log($(this).data('tag_id'); it prints undefined.

Comment: Okay, in the javascript I changed the $(this).data('tag_id') to "tag-id" and it now seems to be working. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, always forget that.  Fixed.